# Wrong number of accounts displayed

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, user-accounts

***[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1833653/extreme-coders)*** is my profile page on Stack Overflow. I have accounts on all 104 Stack Exchange sites including the newest ones. But the profile page is showing only 101 accounts instead of 104. Is this a possible bug?
I must also add that all those accounts are quite old.

**EDIT**

***[This](https://stackexchange.com/users/2055869/extreme-coders?tab=accounts)*** page on Stack Exchange shows all the 104 accounts, so I believe none of the accounts were deleted.

Comment: Maybe some of the sites you had accounts for were deleted, and you only have accounts on 101 active sites?

Comment: can i just ask why would you need all 100+ accounts?

Comment: Why have so many accounts when 96% of them are absolutely useless?

Comment: The second link only shows 103 accounts, have 99 sites at 101 rep and 4 sites with higher rep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a couple: MathOverflow and English Language & Usage.

<s>My count of your profiles is actually 103 and one of them is Area 51 which doesn't count... 103 - Area51 + MO + EL&U gives us 104 sites.</s>

I think I miscounted yours somewhere. I got [104 accounts including Area 51](https://stackexchange.com/users/37099/anna-lear?tab=accounts). You're definitely missing the two sites above, though.

Not sure why 101 is displayed on the profile. Mine also says 101 and I'm guaranteed to have an account on every site, so I'm guessing that some may be excluded based on some criteria. I'll double-check.

Comment: Related? [Why are MO accounts not listed among other SE accounts?](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/58/why-are-mo-accounts-not-listed-among-other-se-accounts)

Comment: I assumed that `101` was a deliberate limit imposed by the developers because it's a number with some kind of educational connotations, and to dissuade people from obsessively creating even more accounts just for the sake of seeing the number increase. My profile has said `101` for ages, even as I've registered for several more accounts.

Comment: Any chance there is hard coded check somewhere that if greater than 101, make it 101? Some sort of "sanity check" from ages ago when there were only few sits? I know it sounds silly, but as programmer I've placed such sanity checks myself. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hah, no. Turns out this had to do with the page size we used when retrieving data from the SE API (which we also use internally, yay). Samo put a fix in that will be rolling out in the next build.

Comment: Cheers, though 101 is weird page size. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard 100 + Area 51. :)

Comment: Oh, that Area 51 stick out from every corner! ;)